# Missing WordPress Content?

Tags: wordpress

I've inherited a website developed in WordPress (something I have only basic experience with), and I've been asked to edit a YouTube embed on one of the permalink-ed pages. I can find the page in question using the Pages listing on the WP Dashboard, but when I go to edit the content - there is no HTML displayed for me to edit, each of the boxes (the large one and the 3 "Additional Content" boxes) are all empty.

There doesn't appear to be any categories or posts either (it's a small, new website).

N.B. I'm currently using WordPress 3.1.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should check your plug-ins to make sure that your videos aren't being handled by a plug-in. If you know that isn't the case than more than likely, the video embed is handled through the template. Go to the place where you would normally edit the content of the page and look on the right side of the screen for a sidebar called page attributes. In that side bar you should something like the following sections: Parent, Template, Order. Under the Template section take a gander at the name of the template that the page is using.

Now boot up the FTP, or whatever you'll use to access the website files, and check the /wp-content/themes/default folder for a file named similar to the template name you saw at the edit page. So say the template name was Super Amazing Template, the file would look like super_amazing_template.php.

Check that page for the handling of the video embeds.

This is really just a guess at how to solve the issue though. There are a lot of different possibilities due to it being wordpress. If that doesn't help, a screen shot might help.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Austin, this is likely handled in the page template. Make sure the name declared in the template page you edit matches the value of the template in the dropdown menu from the WordPress editor. The template name that is displayed there is controlled by a comment of the top of the PHP of the actual template page.

It will look something like this:

```
<?php /*
* Template Name: Value from the dropdown menu here
*/
?>
```